Failed to display Glyphs (points) on Bokeh Google Map graph with valid API key and CSV data
I am attempting to display points (glyphs) on a Bokeh Google Map graph using valid latitude and longitude data from a CSV file. Although the map renders correctly with the specified API key, the circles representing the data points do not appear on the map. I have verified the data types and ensured the map options are set to a relevant location, yet the points remain absent.
Below is what I tried:
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
import pandas as pd

output_file("gmap.html")

edu = pd.read_csv('adult_education.csv')
latitude = edu['Latitude']
longitude = edu['Longitude']

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=50.748165, lng=-122.595148, map_type="roadmap", zoom=5)

p = gmap("Valid API", map_options, title="Vancouver") 
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(lat=latitude.tolist(), 
              lon=longitude.tolist()))

p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=20, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)

show(p)

Below is what I got:

This is what I was expecting:


This could be because of this known bug, which was reported for the versions 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 and fixed in 3.4.2. Make sure that you don't use one of these broken versions.
For reference see the official documentation for the GMAP example in 3.4.1 and in the lastest version.
comment
The p.circle() method is changed in the meanwhile and you will need a raidus parameter or you should change your code and use the p.scatter() method which is suggested.
